# Adding refs to another mongodb collection by matching multiple criteria

Tags: mongodb, join, pymongo

I'm totally new to MongoDB and can't sort this out from the docs.  I have two collections, `TREES` and `PLOTS`.  Every tree is in a plot; every plot has, say, 4-150 trees.  So far the collections look something like this:

```
// TREES
[{"_id": objId(), "Tree": "1", "Project": "Alpha", "Plot": "A", "Year": 1979, "Size": 20},
{"_id": objId(), "Tree": "1", "Project": "Alpha", "Plot": "A", "Year": 1986, "Size": 21},
...
{"_id": objId(), "Tree": "54", "Project": "Omega", "Plot": "Z", "Year": 2016, "Size": 17}]

// PLOTS
[{"_id": objId(), "Plot": "A", "Project": "Alpha", "Year": 1979},
{"_id": objId(), "Plot": "A", "Project": "Alpha", "Year": 1986},
...
{"_id": objId(), "Plot": "Z", "Project": "Omega", "Year": 2016}]
```

I want to add a reference field to all the Trees with the objId of the appropriate Plot document, matching on Project, Plot and Year.  I'd also like to add a refs array to all the Plots to contain the objIds with all of each one's Trees [Edit: Although maybe that's really not necessary?].  The real schemas both have 30-40 fields so embedding would be mad.  The application development will most likely be done in pymongo, if there's anything relevant there.

To Clarify:

My problem is in matching trees to plots on the three criteria -- it seems like `$lookup` is no use here and I've tried `$unionWith` but can't figure it out.  The docs and tutorials are full of toy problems where you add inter-collection references by matching on *one* field... and I can't figure out how to generalize that.  Best result has been from doing

```
db.TREES.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'PLOTS', 
            'localField': 'Plot', 
            'foreignField': 'Plot', 
            'as': 'TooManyPlots'
        }
    }
])
```

That gives me an array of all Plots with the right name -- but from all Years and all Projects, and I can't figure out how to weed that out and arrive at an updated Tree document with just the one correct Plot.

I haven't yet developed the Mongo-vision to see the proper flow for this.
Could be I'm also having some XY trouble -- plus it could be that MongoDB isn't the best fit for our project anyway.  It seems worth a try though.

Comment: Why do your plots have plots?

Comment: @D.SM Oh, just nomenclature issues; same reason the Trees have trees.  If you like you can change both of those to "Name".  I like your noticing that, though I have to say I didn't expect that for the first comment.

Comment: I can't follow what your current state is and what you are asking. If you want references in the data, add some. Make the fields not ambiguous. Remove weird name duplication.

Comment: @D.SM What I'm saying is, how do you construct the aggregation that will add those references?  I'll amend the question a bit.  The field names are completely irrelevant -- these are just toy schemata.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup

Comment: @D.SM Hrrmm... I was looking at that yesterday and couldn't work it out; I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay -- no great mystery to it except for understanding how to understand it.  In hopes of giving someone else a hand here's how I got it to work, closely matching the [doc reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) @D.SM noted in the comments, and my thanks to them.

```
db.TREES.aggregate(
[{$lookup: {
  from: 'Plots',
  let: { tPlot: '$Plot', tProj: '$Project', tYear: '$Year'},
  pipeline: [
    { $match: 
      { $expr: 
        { $and: 
          [{$eq: ['$Plot', '$$tPlot']},
          {$eq: ['$Project', '$$tProj']},
          {$eq: ['$Year', '$$tYear']}]
        }
      }
    },
    { $project: { _id:1} }
    ],
  as: 'Plot_id_A'
} // That does what I wanted; from here it's just tidying things up
}, {$unwind: {
  path: '$Plot_id_A',
}}, {$set: {
  Plot_id: '$Plot_id_A._id'
}}, {$project: {
  Plot_id_A : 0
}}]
```

Note that in the `let:` line the right-hand names are all coming from the  `TREES` collection we're working in, while in the `$and:` the same-named left-hand names are all coming from the `PLOTS` collection we're joining, and so for the loss of clarity there I acknowlege D.SM's beef with my example field names.  Anyway it works.

If anyone has an improvement to suggest though... lemme know!